# java. Как отобразить часть html документа в JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing

Как и многие задающие вопросы, я только начинаю знакомство с java, поэтому прошу ткнуть носом в конкретный пример.

Задача состоит в следующем: это простое приложение на java. Имеется .htm документ (с текстом, картинками, таблицами и подобным вперемешку). Необходимо на JEditorPane отобразить только те абзацы документа .htm, которые содержат заранее известное слово.

Вопрос о JEditorPane, потому что на нем легко и корректно получается отобразить разношерстный документ, но получается только целиком. Если есть более простой подход - буду рад рекомендациям.

Comment: Если часть то в конец и начало текста добавляете <html><body> - в начало и </body></html> в конце. Тогда JEditorPane будет работать с текстом как с html документом.

Comment: Полагаю, абзац - есть тег `<br>`, так? Думаю, можно решить так: загрузить док-т в объект в строку, (String-переменную), (для опытных: не юзаю `StringBuilder` и иже с ними из соображений простоты объяснения) разбить на массив строк по абзацам - тобишь `split("<br>")`, а массив перебрать в foreach-цикле, анализируя каждый абзац на наличие нужного слова через `contains("выражение")`, а при получении совпадения, добавлять в переменную конечного результата. И на сладкое - `textEditor.(setText(rezult));`)